# htaccess redirect from subfolder to specific page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I know there are lots of htaccess redirect questions, and I did look. I don't have any experience with htaccess and the replies have confused me so far. However this is what i am looking to do.

I need to redirect all traffic trying to get to www.mywebsite.com/folder1/ and www.mywebsite.com/folder1 to www.mywebsite.com/folder2/specificpage.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Hannah

Comment: And you tried nothing so far?

Answer (score 0):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^folder1/? /folder2/specificpage.html [L,NC,R=302]
```

PS: Remove `R=302` if you want only internal rewrite.

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)